# On click, if has class then alert, else add the class issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason the code below is firing both conditions at the same time;

so to start with my li has no class, then on click the class "disabled" is being added, but the alert is also popping up on the first click?

```
    $('.select li').on( "click", function() {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('disabled') ) {
      alert("This is disabled");
    }
    else {
      $(this).addClass('disabled');
    }   
    });
```

It should add the class if doesn't already exist on the first click, then if clicked again the alert should then pop up to say this li already has the class disabled

Comment: Make sure you are not adding this listener multiple times.

Comment: Could you add a minimal example that exhibits this behavior? Right now there's not enough information to figure out the issue.

Comment: Please provide a [live demo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) containing a [mcve]

Comment: @Damian Smith I tested this code in isolation for you and it works by adding the class on first click, then alerting on only on the second click. Your code looks fine, it must be something else. Can you provide more info? Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/5tw4r01b/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your event listener is getting triggered twice because the click event first triggered the `<li>` (`e.target`), then the event bubbled back to `ul.select` (`e.currentTarget`). You need to delegate the click event to the list and indicate in event data parameter to `li`. See demo

### Demo

```js
$('.select').on('click', 'li', disableItem);

function disableItem(e) {
  if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
    return console.log('Item is already disabled');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('disabled');
    return console.log('Item has been disabled');
  }
};
```

```css
.select {
  list-style: none
}

.select li {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.disabled {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  width: 350px;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-left: 45%;
}

.as-console-row.as-console-row::after {
  content: '';
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class='select'>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>ITEM</li>
</ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I need some sleep! The listener was being triggered twice due to the checkbox within the li, played around with the script using your advice above and is now working! Thanks

Comment: Happens to me all the time, glad I can help.